# on mouse out event i want the page to refresh the iframe in the div

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

As you soo
if you hover on right on button you get a slide panel which has a iframe.This page on every loads has a diff background.I want on ever new hover to load new background
for which it has to be refreshed.so my question is when hover the div it has to be refreshed then loaded.so how to go about it.

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/Ej5k8/9/

```
<div id="iframeContainer">
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.tumblr.com/index.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: 400+ rep. why post this body's css-style in your question?

Comment: coz its mandatory to put some code after fiddle. im sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before you show the `iframe`, it should set the `src` again making the `iframe` reload

```
$('#iframe')[0].src += '';
```

Comment: @BharathRallapalli nope, it will append `''` which is nothing

Comment: guys im all lost here

Comment: hi Spokey thanks a lot...instead of slide in i reload it while slideout so it a person doesn't see the reload transition. thanks a lot. you were a big help and also in making me understand

Comment: i wanted to load this url in iframe but im unablw to load...any advive? http://www.tumblr.com/assets/html/iframe/teaser.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#follow").mouseenter(function () {

        $("#panel-content").show();
        $("#panel-content").animate({
          width: '300px'
        }, 'fast', function(){
         location.reload();                                         
      });
 });
```

This should help